# How to add an index to a foreign key and save it in a tablespace?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I want to create the table X_REL_REPLICA like this:

```
CREATE TABLE X_REL_REPLICA
(
  CODE_SI               VARCHAR2(10 CHAR),
  ID_SA                 VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
  CODE_SI_SAL           VARCHAR2(10 CHAR),
  ID_SA_SAL         VARCHAR2(30 CHAR),
 CONSTRAINT X_REL_REPLICA_PK PRIMARY KEY (CODE_SI, ID_SA) USING INDEX TABLESPACE APIGTW_INDEX_WORK ENABLE,
 CONSTRAINT X_REL_REPLICA_FK FOREIGN KEY (CODE_SI_SAL, ID_SA_SAL) REFERENCES X_SAL_REPLICA(CODE_SI, ID_SA) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE
```

I want to add to my foreign key `X_REL_REPLICA_FK` an index an save it in the tablespace `APIGTW_INDEX_WORK` exactly like I did it with my primary key. How I'm supposed to perform that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible with `CREATE TABLE` statement.

> #### using_index_clause
>
> You can specify the using_index_clause only when enabling unique or primary key constraints.

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/clauses002.htm#i1002419)

Add index after the table creation.

```
create index <index_name> on X_REL_REPLICA(CODE_SI_SAL, ID_SA_SAL) tablespace <tablespace_name>;
```

Comment: Ok thank you, I solved my problem. Actually, Oracle creates automaticaly an index on my PK but not on my FK so after that the creation of my table I have to execute `CREATE INDEX "X_REL_REPLICA_FK" ON "X_REL_REPLICA" ("CODE_SI_SAL","ID_SA_SAL") TABLESPACE "APIGTW_INDEX_WORK"; `